# Retrieve and save SQLPLUS query result into a variable bash

Tags: database, bash, sqlplus

I am trying to save the response of a query made through SQLPLUS and save it in a local variable, but when i execute the following code, i get the path as output instead of the value of the query, could u please help me? I don't know what am i doing wrong:

```
    #!/bin/bash

SQLPLUS="<Path to sqlplus> -s user/passwd"
X=$SQLPLUS<<EOF_SQL_1
    set heading off;
    select table1 from table 2 where parameter ='Properties';
exit;
EOF_SQL_1
echo  $X
```

The result of this script is " -s user/passwd" when it should be the esult of the query I made. 
Please tell me what am I doing wrong :S

Comment: $SQLPLUS is not a command substitution but a variable expansion $("$SQLPLUS")must be used instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using heredoc and command substitution in the same command would not be recommended, the easier is to use a function

```
fun_sql() {
    sqlplus user/passwd@tnsname <<EOF
...
EOF
}

X=$(fun_sql)
```

Comment: This actually worked, thanks!!
Guess you are right and it needs to be done in different steps